# Give an example of a (path-connected) covering space which is not a regular covering space.

Tags: general-topology

I am having great difficulty with the following qualifying exam problem and would appreciate some help.  Thank you so much in advance.

Give an example of a (path-connected) covering space which is not a regular covering
space.

Answer (score 7):

For sufficiently nice topological spaces, regular covering spaces correspond to normal subgroups of the fundamental group.  So find any space with a fundamental group containing subgroups that aren't normal.

For a specific example, consider $X=S^1\vee S^1$, whose fundamental group is $$G=\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}=\langle a\rangle*\langle b\rangle$$  The subgroup $\langle a\rangle$ is not normal in $G$, and therefore corresponds to a covering space which is not regular.

Check [Hatcher](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATch1.pdf) (pg. 58) for pictures of other nonregular covering spaces, including the one I've just described.  On pg. 58, (3), (4), (9), (10), and (12)-(14) are all nonregular.

Comment: So in this example would any cover of index 2 be an irregular covering?

Comment: Careful.  $\langle a \rangle$ does not have index $2$.  Any subgroup of index $2$ is in fact normal, and thus corresponds to a regular covering.  In the link I gave, (1) and (2) are examples of coverings of index $2$, and both are regular.